How do I place one UV map on one texture image without having two uv map?

Whenever I enlarge the uv map for a logo. It alway appear to have a problem. For example, there two uv map on one uv editing and the texture for the sphere is not matching what the logo show.

You could change the image with the logo in an image editor like Photoshop or Krita, place it where it is supposed to be on the UV map
